# How could we save I/O operations in a two phase sort if we have more buffers than sub-lists?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, io

I am reading [Database Systems: The Complete Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131873253). In one of it's chapters it asks the reader on how would they save I/O operations in a two phase sort if there are more buffers than sub-lists in the second phase.

My initial thought reading it was that if we have a big number of buffers then the two-phase algorithm would simply reduce to a one phase algorithm. It seems to straight forward though so I am not sure if I am correct.

What is the answer to the question above?

Comment: Wouldn't a sub-list take up more space than a single second phase buffer? I assume the first phase creates sub-lists where sub-list size is based on available memory space. I also assume the second phase is a k-way merge, and with 1GB of working ram, a 16-way merge using 17 buffers of size 50MB each (to reduce random access overhead) would be possible. Eventually the second phase reaches a point where there are 16 or fewer sub-lists remaining, and it takes one more merge pass regardless if there are 16 sub-lists or 2 sub-lists, so I don't see where I/O get reduced beyond what would be normal.

Comment: I know, but I would assume what the authors have in mind is something like "We get 10 sub-lists in total, but we have more than 10 buffers". How many more they dont specify. Im only taking this description based on my understanding of that chapter, and the other problems that they have.

Comment: Assuming all sub-lists were stored sequentially on hard disks, then the number of random accesses could be reduced by reading more than one buffer at a time, but this would not reduce the number of I/O operations. Still the same number of reads, only the ordering of those reads would change. If it was possible at the user level to take advantage of scatter / gather so that a single read was done into multiple buffers, this could technically reduce the number of read commands, but the amount of data transferred would remain the same.

Comment: @rcgldr yet one of the most widespread books on the subject has this question in it, so there must be something they want us to take out of it.

Comment: There's not enough information about what the book means by sub-lists or two phase sort. My first comment explains the normal situation, where the first phase uses all of memory like a single buffer to create each sub-list to setup for the second (external) phase of the sort, and in that case sub-list size is much greater than the (k+1) buffers, each buffer with size about 1/(k+1) sub-list size for the second k-way merge phase. Once there are k or fewer sub-lists, it's the last merge cycle of the second phase.